# python matrix when both row and column size are large

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a 2D matrix in python when number of rows and columns are equal and it is around 231000. Most of the cell entries would be zero. 
Some [i][j] entries would be non-zero.

The reason for creating this matrix is to apply SVD and get [U S V] matrices with rank of say 30.

Can anyone provide me with the idea how to implement this by applying proper libraries. I tried pandas Dataframe but it shows Memory error.

I have also seen scipy.sparse matrix but couldn't figure out how it would be applied to find SVD.

Comment: did you try numpy?

Comment: Annnd now I see you probably meant [`scipy.linalg.svd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html), which does *not* work with sparse matrices.

Comment: numpy.ndarray([231000, 231000]) shows the memory error too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sparse matrix svd in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234809/sparse-matrix-svd-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate question, but I'll answer this anyways.

There are several libraries in python aimed at dealing with *partial* svds on very sparse matrices.

My personal preference is `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`, a [ARPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK) implementation of iterative partial SVD calculation.

You can also try the function `sparsesvd.sparsesvd`, which uses the [SVDLIBC](https://pypi.org/project/sparsesvd/) implementation, or `scipy.sparse.linalg.svd`, which uses the [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) implementation.

To convert your table to a format that these algorithms use, you will need to import `scipy.sparse`, which allows you to use the `csc_matrix` [class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html)

Use the above links to help you out. There are a lot of resources already here on stack overflow and many more on the internet.