# Rank of Sparse matrix Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, rank

I have a sparse csr matrix, sparse.csr_matrix(A), for which I would like to compute the matrix rank

There are two options that I am aware of: I could convert it to numpy matrix or array (.todense() or .toarray()) and then use np.linalg.matrix_rank(A), which defeats my purpose of using the sparse matrix format, since I have extremely large matrices. The other option is to compute a SVD decomposition ([sparse matrix svd in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234809/sparse-matrix-svd-in-python)) for a matrix, then deduce matrix rank from this.

Are there any other options for this? Is there currently a standard, most efficient way for me to compute the rank of a sparse matrix? I am relatively new to  doing linear algebra in python, so any alternatives and suggestions with that in mind would be most helpful.

Comment: Try studying and proving algorithms which work for matrices in sparse form, and decide which ones are the best.

Comment: @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ Thank you for taking the time to reply. This is currently what I am doing, but I am looking for some more guidance about what are the standard options available already. This is only one component of a larger problem I am working on, so I would prefer to spend less time researching and comparing algorithms, unless necessary.

Comment: See [scipy.linalg.interpolative.estimate_rank](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.interpolative.estimate_rank.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Denis, but I am not looking for an estimate of rank, but an exact value. I have resorted to using Linbox to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using `.todense()` method and using `rank method of numpy` to calculate the answers.

It has given me a satisfactory answer till now.